# React Router 4 - componentWillReceiveProps() doesn't fire

Tags: reactjs, components, react-router, render, router

I'm using React Router 4.

When I render component with render parameter componentWillReceiveProps() it doesn't fire the fist time, so I need to click twice to sent props to the component.

I render like this:

```
const CartRoute = (props) => (<Cart itemsInCart = {this.state.itemsInCart} deleteItemFromCart = {this.deleteItemFromCart} {...props} />);
.....
  <Switch>
    .....
    <Route path="/cart" render={CartRoute} />
  </Switch>
```

Without Router (when all components are on the same page) it works ok.

Here is detailed description:

[React router - Need to click LINK twice to pass props to Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814173/react-router-need-to-click-link-twice-to-pass-props-to-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Reason is simple one, As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

> React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during
>   mounting. It only calls this method if some of component's props may
>   update. componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new props.

`componentWillReceiveProps` will not get called when first time component get rendered, at that time `componentDidMount` get called, when you do any changes in props values then only `componentWillReceiveProps` will get triggered. So first time if you want to do some calculation do that in `componentDidMount` method, like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
   console.log('props values', this.props); //it will print the props values
}
```

`componentWillReceiveProps` is a Updating lifecycle method not Mounting method.

**Mounting Methods:**

> These methods are called when an instance of a component is being
>   created and inserted into the DOM.

**Updating Methods:**

> An update can be caused by changes to props or state. These methods
>   are called when a component is being re-rendered.

[Check the difference between Mounting and Updating lifecycle method.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank you!

Comment: Was stuck on this for waaaay to long. Thanks for the information!

Comment: @Jay, glad it helped you sir :)